# Deserialize merge-fields and interests that have different names in different MailChimp lists

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, mailchimp-api-v3.0

When deserializing the following json response I manage to get the subscribers id, e-mail and status, which is easy as these names are always the same and are not dependent on the particular settings in a list. But how can I deserialize the merge-fields and the interests that do have different names in different lists?

```
{ "members": [ {
    "id": "f777bbffab8d1ceca8b757df63c47cb8",
    "email_address": "urist.mcvankab+1@freddiesjokes.co",
    "unique_email_id": "882e9bec19",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields":{
        "FNAME": "",
        "LNAME": "" },
    "interests":{
        "9143cf3bd1": true,
        "3a2a927344": false,
        "f9c8f5f0ff": false,
        "f231b09abc": true,
        "bd6e66465f": false },
//And so on...
```

How can I change my classes to deserialize the response?

My Member Class

```
public class Member
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    //public List<MergeField> mergeFields { get; set; }
    //public List<Interests> interests { get; set; }
}
```

Where the MergeField refers to to my old MergeField class, where the fields were hardcoded

```
public class MergeField
{
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public string MERGE4 { get; set; }
}
```

But I would like to use the same two Mergefield(s) classes that I use to deserialize the json response when requesting a list's merge-fields.

```
public class MergeFields
{
    public List<Mergefield> merge_fields { get; set; }
    public string list_id { get; set; }
    public int total_items { get; set; }
}

public class Mergefield
{
    public string merge_id { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string list_id { get; set; }
}
```

I found this answer [How do deserialize JSON with non-standard (and varying) property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750502/how-do-deserialize-json-with-non-standard-and-varying-property-names-in-net), but I cannot figure out how to use it in my scenarío.

Comment: Do you really need the `merge_id`, `tag`, and `name` for each merge field, or do you only want to know the value of all merge fields for each member?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. If possible I would like to get both, but most importantly are the values. Because I can get the name, tag, and id of the merge-fields with the list/<list_id>/merge-field call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<string, object>` type for the merge fields and `Dictionary<string, bool>` type for the interests. Here's what your `Member` class should look like

```
public class Member
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> merge_fields { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> interests { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming you're using `MemberResponse` class for the response like below

```
public class MemberResponse
{
    public List<Member> members { get; set; }
    public string list_id { get; set; }
    public int total_items { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how you get the value for each merge field and interest

```
MemberResponse memberResponse = .... // your code that calls the API

// enumerate members
foreach (var member in memberResponse.members)
{
    // enumerate merge fields
    foreach (var key in member.merge_fields.Keys)
    {
        // when key = "FNAME", value would be the first name of the member
        // when key = "LNAME", value would be the last name of the member
        string value = member.merge_fields[key].ToString();
    }

    // enumerate interests
    foreach (var key in member.interests.Keys)
    {
        // when key = "9143cf3bd1", value would be true
        // when key = "3a2a927344", value would be false
        // ... and so on
        bool value = member.interests[key];
    }

}
```

Unfortunately there's no way to get the `name` and `merge_id` of the merge fields using the `/lists/{list_id}/members` endpoint since the response body only contains the `tag` of the merge fields, i.e `FNAME`, `LNAME`, etc. You'll need to make a separate call to `/lists/{list_id}/merge-fields` endpoint and compare the `tag` of each merge field in order to get the related `name` and `merge_id`.